# How do I change the axis values on a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, axis-labels

I am working on some code where I have to plot `MPG` of all types of cars over several years.  I am using `geom="boxplot"` in R and it returns the boxplots, but puts all the years as the axis values.  I would like it to return all the boxplots, but only list every five years, i.e. `1985, 1990, 1995`, etc.

Below is the following code that I am using:

`qplot(factor(year), comb08, data=car, geom="boxplot", xlab="Year", ylab="MPG")`

Comment: Can you post some part of `car`?

Comment: Otherwise, try `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(Year[1],Year[length(Year)],by=5))` to set 5 year breaks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(scales)
scale_x_date(breaks = "5 years", labels=date_format("%Y"))
```